# How to search url for date pattern and replace forward slash with period in JS or python

Tags: javascript, python

Apologies if this has been asked and answered, but I can't see that it has.

I have a hosted form that i want to prepopulate known data with a query string, which can contain multiple dates. The dates don't populate into the form with a forward slash but do with a period; therefore, I'm looking to put a code step into Zapier so that after the URL is formed I can do that replacement and then encode what's left. Zapier has Javascript or Python.

I've got nowhere in Python, but got this far in JS.

let INPUT = inputData.INPUT;

let OUTPUT = INPUT.replace(/b[\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}]/g, ".");

output = [{INPUT, OUTPUT}];

I think I'm close but every variation on the above either replaces all the forward slashes or replace everything but the dates with periods.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Python solution.

I think this is more or less what you are looking for. Regex could be finetuned for your specific needs.
The `re.sub` function searches for a match in the string, parses it as a `Match` object and executes a function on the grouped `Match` object.
In this case I replaced the usual function call with a lambda function to create a one-liner.

```
import re

url_with_fs_dates = 'www.helloworld.com/test/01/01/2022&01/02/2022222'
url_with_period_dates = re.sub(r'\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}', lambda x: x.group().replace('/','.'), url_with_fs_dates)

print(url_with_period_dates)
# www.helloworld.com/test/01.01.2022&01.02.2022222
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the date can have 1 or 2 digits for both the month and the day and that the entire date must be on a word boundary meaning that there are no alphanumeric or '_' character to the left and right. If this assumption is not correct, then remove each '\b' from the following regex:

```
\b(\d\d?)/(\d\d?)/(\d{4})\b
```

[See RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uteRr0/1)

1. `\b` - Matches the empty string but only at the beginning or end of a word.
2. `(\d\d?)` - Match one or two digits as group 1.
3. `/` - Match '/'.
4. `(\d\d?)` - Match one or two digits as group 2.
5. `/` - Match '/'.
6. `(\d{4})` - Match 4 digits as group 3.
7. `\b` - Matches the empty string but only at the beginning or end of a word.

All matched occurrences are replaced with ...

```
\1.\2.\3
```

where \1, \2 and \3 refer to the group 1, 2 and 3 matches reppectively.

```py
import re

s = 'x=1/1/2023&y=12/25/2023,01/16/2024'

s = re.sub(r'\b(\d\d?)/(\d\d?)/(\d{4})\b', r'\1.\2.\3', s)
print(s)
```

Prints:

```None
x=1.1.2023&y=12.25.2023,01.16.2024
```

**Note**

I am not familiar with all international languages (obviously) and for the ones that I am familiar with the digits that are used with dates are 0, 1, 2, ...9. If this is true for your language, then ideally one should use `[0-9]` instead of `\d`, which could match other digit characters besides `[0-9]`. But I am assuming your input would not contain those characters if they were not in the language that you are using.